# Waiting for keyPress(Macro) to send a message

Tags: c#, text, macros

So I am making a program for a class that I am taking. This programs task is to be able to type a message into a TextBox, and be able to set a key for a macro to send this message in what ever application you are currently in as the C# program is in the background, un-focused.

My problem is that I can not find any code examples to have a program unfocused, wait for a key press and then run this pseudo code:

```
If (KeyPress = F1)
{
Send {Enter};
Send {Text from textbox};
Send {Enter};
}
```

Would there be anybody out there that would have this knowledge and if it is even possible in C#?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Normally you would use a keyboard hook for this, which is possible but definitely non-trivial in C#. A global keyboard shortcut might also work. I suggest you google both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the form events, and double click in KeyPress event, in the method put this logic:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter) //Keys.Enter is your key.
            {
                textBox1.Text == "YOUR TEXT";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the purpose of the form:
1: It is launched
2: You enter text into a text field
3: You minimize form
4: Say you open notepad, press a hotkey
5: When said hotkey is pressed, the form sends a message

Comment: The purpose of the program is to insert text into another program, so instead of changing the texbox's text that is INSIDE of the program that I am making, I want to send the text, emulating a keyboard being typed.

Answer (score 0):

"My problem is that I can not find any code examples to have a program unfocused, wait for a key press"

You're looking to trap a keystroke while your app is NOT in focus.  This cannot be done using standard .Net alone.  The task requires the use of Windows APIs...

There are three possible approaches to this problem.

1. Polling - You can poll the keyboard state with a Timer and the GetAsyncKeyState() API.  While this is technically possible, it is NOT the recommended approach.
2. System Wide Registered Hotkey - You can register a specific hotkey combination with your application using the RegisterHotkey() API.  This is the least resource intense approach of the three options.  There is one huge drawback, however.  If your desired hotkey combination has already been taken by another application then you're SOL (sh!t outa luck).  Check the return value from your registration request to determine if it was successful.
3. Low Level Keyboard Hook - You can trap ALL keyboard keypresses in your app by using a low level keyboard hook via WH_KEYBOARD_LL.  This is the most invasive, albeit versatile option.

Pick your poison and do a search.  There are many examples for all of these approaches out on the net.